# Assigning unknown variable to new variable name

Tags: r, environments

I have to load in many files and tansform their data. Each file contains only one `data.table`, however the tables have various names.

I would like to run a single script over all of the files -- to do so, i must assign the unknown `data.table` to a common name ... say `blob`.

What is the `R` way of doing this? At present, my best guess (which seems like a hack, but works) is to load the `data.table` into a new environment, and then: `assign('blob', get(objects(envir=newEnv)[1], env=newEnv)`.

In a reproducible context this is:

```
newEnv <- new.env()
assign('a', 1:10, envir = newEnv)
assign('blob', get(objects(envir=newEnv)[1], env=newEnv))
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you saved the data.tables using `save()` somewhat like this:

```
d1 <- data.table(value=1:10)
save(d1, file="data1.rdata")
```

and your problem is that when you load the file you don't know the name (here: d1) that you used when saving the file. Correct?

I suggest you use instead `saveRDS()` and `readRDS()` for saving/loading single objects:

```
d1 <- data.table(value=1:10)
saveRDS(d1, file="data1.rds")
blob <- readRDS("data1.rds")
```

Comment: +1 / accepted -- that's exactly what i'm trying to do. works perfectly. thanks very much.

Answer (score 5):

The R way is to create a single object, i.e. a single list of data tables.

Here is some pseudocode that contains three steps:

- Use `list.files()` to create a list of all files in a folder.
- Use `lapply()` and `read.csv()` to read your files and create a list of data frames. Replace `read.csv()` with `read.table()` or whatever is appropriate for your data.
- Use `lapply()` again, this time with `as.data.table()` to convert the data frames to data tables.

The pseudocode:

```
filenames <- list.files("path/to/files")
dat <- lapply(files, read.csv)
dat <- lapply(dat, as.data.table)
```

Your result should be a single list, called `dat`, containing a data table for each of your original files.

Comment: At 5m+ rows the files are too large to handle as a batch, given my 32bit / XP system.